# Neo4j 2.0.1 failing to start

Tags: neo4j, startup, graph-databases, app-startup

I'm an undergrad and I'm using Neo4j for my senior thesis project. I'm running it on a Mac and a few days ago my laptop locked up and I had to shut it down improperly. I'm not sure if this caused my current issues but since then I have been unable to get Neo4j to start. I run `./neo4j start` in the console and the following error occurs:

```
./neo4j start console
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [3403]... waiting for server to be ready....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................../neo4j: line 152:  3403 Abort trap: 6           "$JAVACMD" -cp "${CLASSPATH}" $JAVA_OPTS -Dneo4j.home="${NEO4J_HOME}" -Dneo4j.instance="${NEO4J_INSTANCE}" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper >> "${CONSOLE_LOG}" 2>&1
 Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Here are the contents of the log file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x0000000103f7fd15, pid=3403, tid=32263
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0xfcd15]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f943c0db000):  JavaThread "Statistics Gatherer[primitives]" [_thread_in_vm, id=32263, stack(0x000000010fbd0000,0x000000010fcd0000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr=0x0000000110161000

Registers:
RAX=0x000000077bc45ce8, RBX=0x000000011015e97c, RCX=0x0000000110161a44, RDX=0xfffffffffffffeba
RSP=0x000000010fccee68, RBP=0x000000010fcceeb0, RSI=0x000000000000f87f, RDI=0x000000077bc42c20
R8 =0x0000000000000c34, R9 =0x000000011015e97c, R10=0x0000000104a1b66c, R11=0x00000001042f3297
R12=0x000000010fccefa0, R13=0x00007f943c0db000, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000000000010
RIP=0x0000000103f7fd15, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010282, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000010fccee68)
0x000000010fccee68:   0000000104385665 000000010468ef60
0x000000010fccee78:   00007f943c0db000 00007f943c0db000
0x000000010fccee88:   00000007faeeb010 0000000000000000
0x000000010fccee98:   00000007faeeb010 000000010fccefa8
0x000000010fcceea8:   00007f943c0db000 000000010fccef48
0x000000010fcceeb8:   0000000104a1b698 00000000000030d0
0x000000010fcceec8:   000000010412c705 000000010fcceef0
0x000000010fcceed8:   00007f943b0d4a60 00000007fc0776a0
0x000000010fcceee8:   00007f943b0d4a61 000000010fccef40
0x000000010fcceef8:   0000000103d9dcc8 000000010fccef20
0x000000010fccef08:   000000010fccef08 0000000000000000
0x000000010fccef18:   000000010fccefa8 00000007faeedc40
0x000000010fccef28:   0000000000000000 00000007faeeb010
0x000000010fccef38:   0000000000000000 000000010fccef68
0x000000010fccef48:   000000010fcceff0 0000000104a0f058
0x000000010fccef58:   0000000000000000 0000000104a17cd8
0x000000010fccef68:   00000000000030d0 000000010fccefa0
0x000000010fccef78:   000000011015e97c d9d90da3ec34d281
0x000000010fccef88:   0000000000000000 0000000000000010
0x000000010fccef98:   0000000103d9dce0 000000077bc42c10
0x000000010fccefa8:   00000007a499cf40 000000010fccefb0
0x000000010fccefb8:   00000007faf78c2a 000000010fccf060
0x000000010fccefc8:   00000007faf79ab0 0000000000000000
0x000000010fccefd8:   00000007faf78c58 000000010fccef68
0x000000010fccefe8:   000000010fccf020 000000010fccf0a8
0x000000010fcceff8:   0000000104a0f058 00000000000030d0
0x000000010fccf008:   0000000000000000 0000000000000010
0x000000010fccf018:   0000000000000000 00000000000030d0
0x000000010fccf028:   00000000000030d0 000000011015e97c
0x000000010fccf038:   000000077bbd7580 0000000000000000
0x000000010fccf048:   0000000000000000 0000000000000010
0x000000010fccf058:   0000000104a0f1d4 000000077bc42c10 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000103f7fd15)
0x0000000103f7fcf5:   48 89 74 d1 08 48 83 c2 01 75 f0 49 f7 c0 01 00
0x0000000103f7fd05:   00 00 74 06 8b 70 08 89 71 08 c3 48 8b 74 d0 e8
0x0000000103f7fd15:   48 89 74 d1 e8 48 8b 74 d0 f0 48 89 74 d1 f0 48
0x0000000103f7fd25:   8b 74 d0 f8 48 89 74 d1 f8 48 8b 34 d0 48 89 34 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=
```

Last night I deleted the Neo4j folder except for graph.db and downloaded the newest version, so I upgraded from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1. However the startup error persists.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Time is ticking on my deadline! Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the messages.log text, it's quite long.

https://gist.github.com/ottoborden/8948642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log files you've listed don't mention 2.0.1 at all, only 2.0.0.

I'd try downloading Neo4j 2.0.0 again, and seeing if that works successfully. If it does, then try cleanly shutting down, and starting the upgrade process again. It's possible that the unclean shutdown you did earlier prevents Neo4j from upgrading properly.

More practically, I'd also recommend just getting to a working state with 2.0.0, assuming you don't need a feature with 2.0.1.

Comment: @obordon - did this suggestion get you going again? I couldn't see anything unusual in the messages.log, weird error!

Answer (score 1):

Can you upload graph.db/messages.log - that probably has some sort of error message that will explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue when trying to open a database with an older version of Noe4j server than the one it was created. Using same versions just did it, but finding out the problem wasn't the most obvious.

Looking in graph.db/messages.log As Mark suggested helped as the message from console.log was less informative to me, saying just "Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery.." .